# how to retrieve pdf file in bytes from database and show it on iframe in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, pdf

I have to display pdf file content from database to iframe of a page since I donot want to show any kind of url and file name. Even I do not want the pdf to be generated. I just want to show the pdf content on screen.

Please help me out for this.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to generate the PDF where the content of the PDF will be stored? Will it be dumped in DB before?

You can output the PDF content by setting the content type as application/pdf. If the browser is capable of rendering, it will be displayed in browser itself or else it will be downloaded to their local machine.

Comment: Hi Balaji, The pdf data is stored in database so I have to extract the content and show it on iframe.

Comment: then you can output the PDF content by setting the content type as application/pdf. If the browser is capable of rendering, it will be displayed in browser itself or else it will be downloaded to their local machine.